# Compile linux kernel error

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, compiling

As a novice in linux kernel compilation, it's my first time to compile a Linux kernel for myself (I'm trying to use other TCP congestion control algorithms).

I followed the steps in [How to Compile a Linux Kernel](https://www.linux.com/learn/intro-to-linux/2018/4/how-compile-linux-kernel-0). When trying to run `make`, I get an error:

```
✘ XPS-13-9360  ~/linux_compile/linux-5.1.18  make                     
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  CALL    scripts/atomic/check-atomics.sh
  DESCEND  objtool
  CC       /home/soar/linux_compile/linux-5.1.18/tools/objtool/arch/x86/decode.o
In file included from /usr/include/gelf.h:32:0,
                 from arch/x86/../../elf.h:22,
                 from arch/x86/decode.c:26:
/usr/include/libelf.h:46:4: error: unknown type name ‘Elf32_Word’
    Elf32_Word   ch_type;        /* Compression format.  */
    ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/libelf.h:47:4: error: unknown type name ‘Elf32_Word’
    Elf32_Word   ch_size;        /* Uncompressed data size.  */
    ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/libelf.h:48:4: error: unknown type name ‘Elf32_Word’
    Elf32_Word   ch_addralign;   /* Uncompressed data alignment.  */
    ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/libelf.h:53:4: error: unknown type name ‘Elf64_Word’
    Elf64_Word   ch_type;        /* Compression format.  */
    ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/libelf.h:54:4: error: unknown type name ‘Elf64_Word’
    Elf64_Word   ch_reserved;
    ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/libelf.h:55:4: error: unknown type name ‘Elf64_Xword’
    Elf64_Xword  ch_size;        /* Uncompressed data size.  */
    ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/libelf.h:56:4: error: unknown type name ‘Elf64_Xword’
    Elf64_Xword  ch_addralign;   /* Uncompressed data alignment.  */
    ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/libelf.h:253:8: error: unknown type name ‘Elf32_Ehdr’
 extern Elf32_Ehdr *elf32_getehdr (Elf *__elf);
        ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/libelf.h:255:8: error: unknown type name ‘Elf64_Ehdr’
 extern Elf64_Ehdr *elf64_getehdr (Elf *__elf);
        ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/libelf.h:258:8: error: unknown type name ‘Elf32_Ehdr’
 extern Elf32_Ehdr *elf32_newehdr (Elf *__elf);
        ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/libelf.h:260:8: error: unknown type name ‘Elf64_Ehdr’
 extern Elf64_Ehdr *elf64_newehdr (Elf *__elf);
        ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/libelf.h:269:8: error: unknown type name ‘Elf32_Phdr’
 extern Elf32_Phdr *elf32_getphdr (Elf *__elf);
        ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/libelf.h:271:8: error: unknown type name ‘Elf64_Phdr’
 extern Elf64_Phdr *elf64_getphdr (Elf *__elf);
        ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/libelf.h:274:8: error: unknown type name ‘Elf32_Phdr’
 extern Elf32_Phdr *elf32_newphdr (Elf *__elf, size_t __cnt);
        ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/libelf.h:276:8: error: unknown type name ‘Elf64_Phdr’
 extern Elf64_Phdr *elf64_newphdr (Elf *__elf, size_t __cnt);
        ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/libelf.h:283:43: error: unknown type name ‘Elf32_Off’; did you mean ‘Elf32_Chdr’?
 extern Elf_Scn *elf32_offscn (Elf *__elf, Elf32_Off __offset);
                                           ^~~~~~~~~
                                           Elf32_Chdr
/usr/include/libelf.h:285:43: error: unknown type name ‘Elf64_Off’; did you mean ‘Elf64_Chdr’?
 extern Elf_Scn *elf64_offscn (Elf *__elf, Elf64_Off __offset);
                                           ^~~~~~~~~
                                           Elf64_Chdr
/usr/include/libelf.h:325:8: error: unknown type name ‘Elf32_Shdr’
 extern Elf32_Shdr *elf32_getshdr (Elf_Scn *__scn);
        ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/libelf.h:327:8: error: unknown type name ‘Elf64_Shdr’
 extern Elf64_Shdr *elf64_getshdr (Elf_Scn *__scn);
        ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from arch/x86/../../elf.h:22:0,
                 from arch/x86/decode.c:26:
/usr/include/gelf.h:44:9: error: unknown type name ‘Elf64_Half’
 typedef Elf64_Half GElf_Half;
         ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/gelf.h:47:9: error: unknown type name ‘Elf64_Word’
 typedef Elf64_Word GElf_Word;
         ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/gelf.h:48:9: error: unknown type name ‘Elf64_Sword’
 typedef Elf64_Sword GElf_Sword;
         ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/gelf.h:51:9: error: unknown type name ‘Elf64_Xword’
 typedef Elf64_Xword GElf_Xword;
         ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/gelf.h:52:9: error: unknown type name ‘Elf64_Sxword’
 typedef Elf64_Sxword GElf_Sxword;
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/gelf.h:55:9: error: unknown type name ‘Elf64_Addr’
 typedef Elf64_Addr GElf_Addr;
         ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/gelf.h:58:9: error: unknown type name ‘Elf64_Off’
 typedef Elf64_Off GElf_Off;
         ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/gelf.h:62:9: error: unknown type name ‘Elf64_Ehdr’
 typedef Elf64_Ehdr GElf_Ehdr;
         ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/gelf.h:65:9: error: unknown type name ‘Elf64_Shdr’
 typedef Elf64_Shdr GElf_Shdr;
         ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/gelf.h:70:9: error: unknown type name ‘Elf64_Section’
 typedef Elf64_Section GElf_Section;
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/gelf.h:73:9: error: unknown type name ‘Elf64_Sym’
 typedef Elf64_Sym GElf_Sym;
         ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/gelf.h:77:9: error: unknown type name ‘Elf64_Syminfo’
 typedef Elf64_Syminfo GElf_Syminfo;
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/gelf.h:80:9: error: unknown type name ‘Elf64_Rel’
 typedef Elf64_Rel GElf_Rel;
         ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/gelf.h:83:9: error: unknown type name ‘Elf64_Rela’
 typedef Elf64_Rela GElf_Rela;
         ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/gelf.h:86:9: error: unknown type name ‘Elf64_Phdr’
 typedef Elf64_Phdr GElf_Phdr;
         ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/gelf.h:92:9: error: unknown type name ‘Elf64_Dyn’
 typedef Elf64_Dyn GElf_Dyn;
         ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/gelf.h:96:9: error: unknown type name ‘Elf64_Verdef’
 typedef Elf64_Verdef GElf_Verdef;
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/gelf.h:99:9: error: unknown type name ‘Elf64_Verdaux’
 typedef Elf64_Verdaux GElf_Verdaux;
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/gelf.h:102:9: error: unknown type name ‘Elf64_Verneed’
 typedef Elf64_Verneed GElf_Verneed;
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/gelf.h:105:9: error: unknown type name ‘Elf64_Vernaux’
 typedef Elf64_Vernaux GElf_Vernaux;
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/gelf.h:109:9: error: unknown type name ‘Elf64_Versym’
 typedef Elf64_Versym GElf_Versym;
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/gelf.h:113:9: error: unknown type name ‘Elf64_auxv_t’
 typedef Elf64_auxv_t GElf_auxv_t;
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/gelf.h:117:9: error: unknown type name ‘Elf64_Nhdr’
 typedef Elf64_Nhdr GElf_Nhdr;
         ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/gelf.h:121:9: error: unknown type name ‘Elf64_Move’
 typedef Elf64_Move GElf_Move;
         ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/gelf.h:125:9: error: unknown type name ‘Elf64_Lib’
 typedef Elf64_Lib GElf_Lib;
         ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/gelf.h:232:8: error: unknown type name ‘Elf32_Word’; did you mean ‘GElf_Word’?
        Elf32_Word *__xshndx);
        ^~~~~~~~~~
        GElf_Word
/usr/include/gelf.h:238:6: error: unknown type name ‘Elf32_Word’; did you mean ‘GElf_Word’?
      Elf32_Word __xshndx);
      ^~~~~~~~~~
      GElf_Word
arch/x86/decode.c: In function ‘is_x86_64’:
arch/x86/decode.c:43:19: error: request for member ‘e_machine’ in something not a structure or union
  switch (elf->ehdr.e_machine) {
                   ^
arch/x86/decode.c:44:7: error: ‘EM_X86_64’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘is_x86_64’?
  case EM_X86_64:
       ^~~~~~~~~
       is_x86_64
arch/x86/decode.c:44:7: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
arch/x86/decode.c:46:7: error: ‘EM_386’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘EM_X86_64’?
  case EM_386:
       ^~~~~~
       EM_X86_64
In file included from arch/x86/decode.c:28:0:
arch/x86/decode.c:49:51: error: request for member ‘e_machine’ in something not a structure or union
   WARN("unexpected ELF machine type %d", elf->ehdr.e_machine);
                                                   ^
arch/x86/../../warn.h:58:14: note: in definition of macro ‘WARN’
   objname, ##__VA_ARGS__)
              ^~~~~~~~~~~
arch/x86/decode.c:52:1: error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]
 }
 ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
mv: cannot stat '/home/soar/linux_compile/linux-5.1.18/tools/objtool/arch/x86/.decode.o.tmp': No such file or directory
/home/soar/linux_compile/linux-5.1.18/tools/build/Makefile.build:96: recipe for target '/home/soar/linux_compile/linux-5.1.18/tools/objtool/arch/x86/decode.o' failed
make[4]: *** [/home/soar/linux_compile/linux-5.1.18/tools/objtool/arch/x86/decode.o] Error 1
/home/soar/linux_compile/linux-5.1.18/tools/build/Makefile.build:139: recipe for target 'arch/x86' failed
make[3]: *** [arch/x86] Error 2
Makefile:50: recipe for target '/home/soar/linux_compile/linux-5.1.18/tools/objtool/objtool-in.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/soar/linux_compile/linux-5.1.18/tools/objtool/objtool-in.o] Error 2
Makefile:66: recipe for target 'objtool' failed
make[1]: *** [objtool] Error 2
Makefile:1699: recipe for target 'tools/objtool' failed
make: *** [tools/objtool] Error 2
```

In libelf.h:
[image]
and elf.h[image]
then I found [it's been reported before](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1528020), but it's still without any solution. What can I do?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but are you actually trying to compile in congestion control algorithms other than what is already available through `sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_available_congestion_control`?

Comment: Actually I'm trying to improve the already available algorithms(bbr) performance in mobility network...And I write log in the bbr source code to find out how its bandwidth, cnwd, and rtt changes  in different settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I figure out this by myself.
It's look like the compiler could not find the header as my view.
use the `env` command, the CPATH is not in `/usr/include/` but `/home/user/.local/include:$CPATH`,so I change the CPATH to `/usr/include/`, using the method of [lkraemer](https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2005444.html)，but it's still could not work out, and the env reveal that the CPATH has been `/usr/include/`. I think it will be difficult to solve  and shutdown my ubuntu and take a break. But I turn on my ubuntu this morning, it works out.